# Is having many small wcf services better then one?

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server

I developing software for taxi services. My software consist from wcf service as server and wpf application as client. Functionality is growing and my wcf service has more then 50 methods now. I thinking about split my one big WCF service to couple of small services.
Is it a good idea to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes if you can define a clear separation of responsibilities for each of your services. You should try to avoid or minimize coupling between services though. Keep in mind you'll break existing clients if you do change the contract, but it sounds like you are in control of these.

This is quite a common scenario, and you can help yourself by ensuring your service layer is essentially a facade to make it easier to move things around.

Answer (score 0):

IME, if splitting the service up would just create a lot of replicated code for common functionality (like DB access), or would complicate things by needing to add stuff like additional functionality for the services to talk to each other, I would suggest no.

Another reason: your fault-tolerant scenarios now become more complicated.  It is one thing if your entire monolithic service dies - then nothing works.  But if you have 4 related services that need to work together, you now have to intelligently handle partial failure scenarios like what happens if service #3 goes down, and the other services have half-done jobs that need it.  Now you have to be able to get things back to a consistent state while waiting for #3 to come back up, or be able to persist stuff so you can get back to it when it does.  Your number of error messages had just increased as well.